# Simple Python Pong Game

Tags: python, beginner, game

I'm trying to code a machine learning version of pong in python. So far, all I have is the game without any AI.

I personally have very little experience with Python and coding in general, so any feedback would really help! If possible, I'd like to know what the common best practices are when working on a project like this and to what degree I am complying with those practices.

Anyway, here is the code:

```
import pygame

### Colors
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)

### Constants
W = 600
H = 600
pygame.font.init()
comic = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 30)

### Variables
wt = 10
mplay = False

p1x = W/30
p1y = H/2 - ((W/60)**2)/2

p2x = W-(W/30)
p2y = H/2 - ((W/60)**2)/2

p1score = 0
p2score = 0

w_p = False
s_p = False
wsr = False
u_p = False
d_p = False
udr = False

dm = H/40

paddle_width = W/60
paddle_height = paddle_width**2

bsd = 1

bx = W/2
by = H/2
bw = W/65
bxv = H/60
bxv = -bxv
byv = 0

### Functions
def drawpaddle(x, y, w, h):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (x, y, w, h))

def drawball(x, y):
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, WHITE, (int(x), int(y)), int(bw))

def uploc():
    global p1y
    global p2y
    if w_p:
        if p1y-(dm) < 0:
            py1 = 0
        else:
            p1y -= dm
    elif s_p:
        if p1y+(dm)+paddle_height > H:
            p1y = H-paddle_height
        else:
            p1y += dm
    if u_p:
        if p2y-(dm) < 0:
            p2y = 0
        else:
            p2y -= dm
    elif d_p:
        if p2y+(dm)+paddle_height > H:
            p2y = H-paddle_height
        else:
            p2y += dm

def upblnv():
    global bx
    global bxv
    global by
    global byv
    global p2score
    global p1score

    if (bx+bxv < p1x+paddle_width) and ((p1y < by+byv+bw) and (by+byv-bw < p1y+paddle_height)):
        bxv = -bxv
        byv = ((p1y+(p1y+paddle_height))/2)-by
        byv = -byv/((5*bw)/7)
    elif bx+bxv < 0:
        p2score += 1
        bx = W/2
        bxv = H/60
        by = H/2
        byv = 0
    if (bx+bxv > p2x) and ((p2y < by+byv+bw) and (by+byv-bw < p2y+paddle_height)):
        bxv = -bxv
        byv = ((p2y+(p2y+paddle_height))/2)-by
        byv = -byv/((5*bw)/7)
    elif bx+bxv > W:
        p1score += 1
        bx = W/2
        bxv = -H/60
        by = H/2
        byv = 0
    if by+byv > H or by+byv < 0:
        byv = -byv

    bx += bxv
    by += byv

def drawscore():
    score = comic.render(str(p1score) + " - " + str(p2score), False, WHITE)
    screen.blit(score, (W/2,30))

### Initialize
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((W, H))
pygame.display.set_caption('Snake ML v.1.0.0')
screen.fill(BLACK)
pygame.display.flip()

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                w_p = True
                if s_p == True:
                    s_p = False
                    wsr = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                s_p = True
                if w_p == True:
                    w_p = False
                    wsr = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                u_p = True
                if d_p == True:
                    d_p = False
                    udr = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                d_p = True
                if u_p == True:
                    u_p = False
                    udr = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                w_p = False
                if wsr == True:
                    s_p = True
                    wsr = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                s_p = False
                if wsr == True:
                    w_p = True
                    wsr = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                u_p = False
                if udr == True:
                    d_p = True
                    udr = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                d_p = False
                if udr == True:
                    u_p = True
                    udr = False

    screen.fill(BLACK)
    uploc()
    upblnv()
    drawscore()
    drawball(bx, by)
    drawpaddle(p1x, p1y, paddle_width, paddle_height)
    drawpaddle(p2x, p2y, paddle_width, paddle_height)
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.wait(wt)
```

Comment: That's a lot of awfully short variable names. How do you keep track of what they mean? What parts have you implemented so far, what's still missing and are the parts implemented working as intended?

Answer (score 7):

First of all, welcome to CodeReview!

*I'd like to know what the common best practices are when working on a project*

1. **naming**

   It has been mentioned in the comments by @mast, naming is a very important part of coding. Would you still understand this code after a hiatus of a few months? I have a hard time understanding the code as is. I would have been able to give a better review if your code was more readable. *Good* code should be readable at first glance, the below variables have no meaning for me...

   > ```
   > bsd = 1
   > bx = W/2
   > by = H/2
   > bw = W/65
   > bxv = H/60
   > bxv = -bxv
   > byv = 0
   > ```
2. Divide code into more **functions/classes**!

   You say you want to make it run by an AI... as is, your code would require a heck of a rewrite. But if you would have divided your code into more functions,  the AI can reuse a lot of the functions you created for a single player game, and thus making your code easier to maintain, or add functionality.

   What functions/classes should a game of pong have?

   - a Player (class) <-- This player class can be used by both Players.

     ```
     class Player:
         """A player class
            name: a string of the Players name
            paddle_x: an int of the players paddle x position
            paddle_y: an int of the players paddle y position
            score: The score of the player
            movement_keys: list of Keys used to move the player [pygame.K_DOWN, ...]"""
         def __init__(self, name, paddle_x, paddle_y, score, movement_keys):
             pass

         def move(self, dy):
             pass

         def draw_paddle(self):
             pass
     ```
   - a Pong enviroment (class)

     ```
     class Pong:
         def __init__(self, players):
             pass

         def start_game(self):
             pass

         def reset_game(self):
             pass
     ```

   Using a structure like this will improve the code alot, and adding an AI (or other improvements will be easier after this)
3. Avoid working in the global namespace

   This point is interwoven with *dividing the code into functions/classes*, see [this link](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad) as to WHY working in the global namespace is considered bad.
4. Wrap up your code into a `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard.

   This will make your code be runnable from the command line, while also be able to be imported into other scripts